# What is the original radius function for circle pack?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, circle-pack

I'm interested in tweaking the radius of the circles on the circle pack layout. For that I need to know how the original radius is calculated.

By reading the [d3.js source code for pack layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/pack.js) it seems the default radius function is simply  `Math.sqrt` of `value` for each node. But that is not really the case because I modified the  [D3.js original circle pack example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530)  adding a `.radius(function(d){return Math.sqrt(d);})`  and as you can see at [bl.ocks.org/ecerulm/f0a36710e3](http://bl.ocks.org/ecerulm/f0a36710e3ccbf0cfc01) the radius of the circles are not the same.

Comment: You need to return the value -- `.radius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d); })`

Comment: Corrected the question, I was already using return in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `d3.layout.pack()` uses `Math.sqrt` as `radius` function. But `pack.nodes` will apply a scale transform `d3_layout_packTransform(node, x, y, k)` to make the whole circle pack chart to fit if `radius` **wasn't explicitly set**. That is why if you apply you own function (even if its  `radius(Math.sqrt)`) you will need to apply your own scaling after if you want to get the same result as with implicit radius.

In the example below I explicitly set `Math.sqrt` as the radius function and then scale afterward to fit `[diameter,diameter]` with my own function `pack_transform` since `d3_layout_packTranform` is not accesible:

```
var pack = d3.layout.pack()
  .value(function(d) { return d.size; })
  .radius(Math.sqrt)
  .size([diameter - 4, diameter - 4]);

var packnodes = pack.nodes(root);
var packroot = packnodes[0];
var w = diameter, h = diameter;
function pack_transform(node, k) {
    function inner_transform(node,cx,cy,k) { 
      var children = node.children;
      node.x = cx + k * (node.x-cx);
      node.y = cy + k * ( node.y-cy);
      node.r *= k;
      if (children) {
        var i = -1, n = children.length;
        while (++i < n) inner_transform(children[i],cx,cy,  k);
      }
    }
    return inner_transform(node,node.x,node.y,k);
}
pack_transform(packroot,  1 / Math.max(2 * packroot.r / w, 2 * packroot.r / h));
```